# form submission in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two fields in the form, but i am not able to post the data to the server. I know  how to submit single filed but how do  i submit multiple field in the form.
below is the code of 2 fields

```
  class Createstudent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: '',
 age:''
  };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    this.setState({age:event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
      alert(this.state.name);
    axios.post('/create',{values:this.state.name,ages:this.state.age})
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    })




  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Age:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.age} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: what ever i type in the name field , the same value  will also be present in the age field how do i over come this

Comment: I think i am doing wrong in handle change event method for multiple fields.

Comment: @AbhilashMuttalli add unique `name` attributes to the form elements.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is you are updating both the `fields` with the same value, on change of any one, update the specific field, it will work, try this:

```
handleChange(event) {
    if(event.target.name == 'name')
        this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    else
        this.setState({age: event.target.value});
}
```

or

```
handleChange(event) {
   this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
}
```

Add `name` attr to `input` field to identify them uniquely, Use this `render` method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" name='name' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Age:
          <input type="text" name='age' value={this.state.age} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Check the `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/dp0an79f/

Comment: now The name field it's not taking the value, only age field is taking. And also u have given if and else their is a problem in that only one condition works. so i think it's taking only age filed

Comment: meaning of if else is, if you enter any thing in name field only name field will get updated, else age field, i think u forgot to add name value to input fields.

Comment: Here i am taking both fields and sending it to the server .

Comment: but before sending you need to accept the input from the user, once user will provide both the value then only you will send the values to server. if you update same value in both the field then if user enter name, age will also get updated, vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code like this.And its working.

```
  import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    class Createstudent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: '',
     age:''
      };

      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }




      handleSubmit(event) {
          alert(this.state.name);
        axios.post('/create',{values:this.state.name,ages:this.state.age})
        .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
        })




      }

      componentDidMount(){


      }

      render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Age:
              <input type="text" value={this.state.age} onChange={e => this.setState({ age: e.target.value })} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        );
      }
    }
```